# generate subset of given set

Tags: c++, vector

here is my  effort  for generate  of subset  of given  set

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> getsubset(vector<int> &sets)
{

       vector<int>allsubset;
       int max=1<<sets.size();
        for (int i=0;i<max;i++){
             vector<int> subset;
             int j=i;
             int index=0;
             while( j>0){
             if ((j&1)>0)
             subset.push_back(sets[index]);
             j>>=1;
             index++;       




                    }


              allsubset.push_back(subset);           

            }

         return allsubset;
       }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

but here is error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: subset, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  subset.cpp
1>c:\users\daviti\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\subset\subset\subset.cpp(27): error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'int &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'int'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and i did not understand error totally,please help me,what is wrong?

Comment: Please avoid drastic changes. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to push_back a `vector<int>` to a `vector<int>` container...it makes no sense.
What you can do is pushing a `int` to a `vector<int>` container.

I would correct the definition of `allsubset` from `vector <int>` to `vector< vector<int> >`

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<int>allsubset;
vector<int> subset;
allsubset.push_back(subset);
```

You're trying to add a `vector<int>` to a `vector<int>`, which is illegal.

Do you want `allsubset` to be `vector<vector<int> >`?

Answer (score 2):

problem is here:

allsubset.push_back(subset);

subset is a vector of integers. You can not pus it back into another vector of integers

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by this line of code:

```
allsubset.push_back(subset);
```

as it is attempting to treat a `vector<int>` as an `int`.

Change `allsubset`, and return value of `getsubset()`, to:

```
vector<vector<int> > getsubset(vector<int> &sets)
{
    vector<vector<int> > allsubset;

    ...
    return allsubset;
}
```

Comment: just `return allsubset;`: but change both the type of `allsubset` and the return type from `getsubset()`.

Comment: i have changed but  it does not work,runtime error,what  can i do?

Comment: Can post the invocation code? I just tried it after the modified changes and it seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the compiler error, but the `allsubset.push_back(subset);` line is definitely wrong - `allsubset` is a `vector<int>`, not a `vector< vector<int> >`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is this line:

```
allsubset.push_back(subset);
```

since `allsubset.push_back()` requires an `int` you get the error because `subset` is of type `vector<int>`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is that you are trying to represent all subsets using the same data structure as the original set. A set of all subsets will be a vector of vectors of ints, not a plain vector of ints.

```
vector< vector<int> > getsubset(vector<int> &sets) {
    vector< vector<int> > allsubset;
    // your code here...
    return allsubset;
}
```

It is a good idea to properly pluralize your variable names, for example

- getsubset should be getsubsets
- allsubset should be allsubsets